# Read user input from console from arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

Hi I'm using visual studio 2010 to learn some C#, at the moment I'm doing arrays in a console application

i have created an array that gives the output I'm looking for. here is the code I'm using for my array

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var lottery_numbers = new[] { "1,", "2, ", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", lottery_numbers[i]);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

i also know that to get a user to input to the console i would need some code similar to the following:

```
        string numbLine;
        Console.WriteLine("display number lines: ");
        numbLine = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
```

what i can't seam to figure out is i want the user to be asked how many lines to be output then it would display that number of lines from the array for user inputs

for example the user would be asked

how many lines for output
the user would put 5
the console would then output the first 5 lines from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take the number from user and loop through that number.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var lottery_numbers = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };
            //Asking for user input
            Console.WriteLine("How many number's you want to display?? ");

            // getting input from user
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // loop through the number user gave as input
            for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", lottery_numbers[i]);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("how many lines for output: ");
var numbLine = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (var i = 0; i < numbLine; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", lottery_numbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to print X lines, you simply change the upper bound of the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", lottery_numbers[i]);
```

becomes

```
int howManyLinesToOutput = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < howManyLinesToOutput; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", lottery_numbers[i]);
```

So far so good?

Next you have to figure out how to set howManyLinesToOutput based on what the user has entered.  Console.ReadLine() seems like what we want, but it returns a string.  How do we change the string to an integer?  We parse it.

Here's one way to parse an int:

```
string numbLine = Console.ReadLine();
int howManyLinesToOutput = int.Parse(numbLine);
```

Here's another way:

```
string numbLine = Console.ReadLine();
int howManyLinesToOutput = Convert.ToInt32(numbLine);
```

Put the above together and your homework assignment should be easy.

---

### Extra credit

What if the user doesn't enter a number?  You'd get an error.  Here's a way around it

```
int howManyLinesToOutput;
bool numberEnteredFlag = false;
while (!numberEnteredFlag)
{
    string numbLine = Console.ReadLine();
    numberEnteredFlag = int.TryParse(numbLine, out howManyLinesToOutput);
}
```

For even more extra credit, modify the above code to handle the condition where the user has entered a negative number.

Comment: i love how no matter what people ask on this site people automatically think its a homework assignment, thanks for the extra help dealing with errors

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not an expert in C# without doing any coding beofore in my life, and if i as to chose a project then yes i would pick something more interesting but pointless picking something inserting or harder if i don't even know the basics

Again thanks for your help and your input ill put your advice to better use in my future with C#